# download large file from node http server,the server out of memory

Tags: node.js

I write a simple http server,and download a large file(1.5G),the server crash by out of memory

my code as follows:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var filename = "file.iso";

var serv = http.createServer(function(req,res){
     var stat = fs.statSync(filename);
     res.writeHeader(200,{"Content-Length":stat.size});
     var fReadStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
     fReadStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
        res.write(chunk);
     });
     fReadStream.on('end', function () {
        res.end();
     });
 });

serv.listen(8888);
```

but when I change to use `pipe` method of stream,it ok,like this:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var filename = "file.iso";

var serv = http.createServer(function(req,res){
     var stat = fs.statSync(filename);
     res.writeHeader(200,{"Content-Length":stat.size});
     var fReadStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
     fReadStream.pipe(res);
 });

serv.listen(8888);
```

my question is why the first code do not work?

Comment: Add  `console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);` inside the on('data') callback.

Comment: Never mind.  I had to look at some code I have to see why it happens.  It is happening later in the code (see answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been working with large files in Node and have noticed that the async calls to load the data can complete far faster than the write calls in the http stream.  This results in a bottleneck that will crash your server because it runs out of memory with all the outstanding write requests (sitting in the buffer).  Piping is designed to manage the stream so that this does not happen.

[From Node documentation:](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)

readable.pipe(destination, [options])#

destination Writable Stream The destination for writing data
options Object Pipe options
end Boolean End the writer when the reader ends. Default = true
This method pulls all the data out of a readable stream, and writes it to the supplied destination, automatically managing the flow so that the destination is not overwhelmed by a fast readable stream.

Comment: This is totally correct, just wanted to add that this is commonly referred to as `backpressure` in the Node community.

Answer (score 3):

we can balance read and write without `pipe`like this：

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var filename = "file.iso";

var serv = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var stat = fs.statSync(filename);
    res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Length": stat.size});
    var fReadStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    fReadStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
       if(!res.write(chunk)){
           fReadStream.pause();
       }
   });
   fReadStream.on('end', function () {
      res.end();
   });
   res.on("drain", function () {
      fReadStream.resume();
   });
});

serv.listen(8888);
```

Comment: Nice code, Since it wrote on 2014, is there  any better version of code ?

Comment: the better version is `pipe`, but if you check every chunk which is send, this version is better,

Comment: tested the code with 3-5GB file, it works like awesome :)